# How to pull image from Docker hub to EC2 using bitbucket pipeline

Tags: amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines, dockerhub

I am trying to implement CICD using bitbucket pipelines.
So far I was able to create the image and push it to docker hub. Seems straightforward and the internet is full of tutorials.
But, to pull the image from an EC2 instance and run the image I didnt find anything.
I have this bitbucket-pipeline.yml file:

```
image: atlassian/default-image:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        services:
          - docker
        script:
          - export IMAGE_NAME=juanibe/vinimayapi:$BITBUCKET_COMMIT
          - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .
          - docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
          - docker push $IMAGE_NAME
```

And I have this script, but I dont know where tu put it:

```
#!bin/bash
sudo docker ps
echo 'Login in to docker'
docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD // How can I set env variable here?
echo 'Fetching latest image'
sudo docker pull user/vinimayapi:latest
echo 'Stoping current container'
sudo docker stop cont_docker_app_test
echo 'Removing old container'
sudo docker rm cont_docker_app_test-old
echo 'Rename stoped container'
sudo docker rename user/cont_docker_app_test user/cont_docker_app_test_old
echo 'Starting new container'
sudo docker run -d --name cont_docker_app_test -p 443:3333 -p 8001:8001 --link my-mongo-testing:my-mongo-testing user/vinimayapi:latest
```

Any help will be really appreciated, I've been trying to create a pipeline for days without success.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your pipeline additional step:

```
  - pipe: "atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.4"
          variables:
            SSH_USER: user
            SERVER: ip_server
            SSH_KEY: sshkey
            MODE: script
            COMMAND: script.sh
```

It should look like below:

```
    image: atlassian/default-image:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        services:
          - docker
        script:
          - export IMAGE_NAME=juanibe/vinimayapi:$BITBUCKET_COMMIT
          - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .
          - docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
          - docker push $IMAGE_NAME
          - pipe: "atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.4"
            variables:
              SSH_USER: user
              SERVER: ip_server
              SSH_KEY: sshkey
              MODE: script
              COMMAND: script.sh
```

script.sh file located in that case is located in the same directory as bitbucket_pipelines.yml